# Parse a json data from internal json file using Angular throwns error

Tags: json, angular, components

I tried to get json from tne internal json file within angular.

with this service (village.service):

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RecordsService {

data: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getVillages(id) {
 return this.http.get('../assets/data/villages.json')
    .map(data => {
       this.data = data.json();
       return data.json();
    }, err => {
    if (err) {
      return err.json();
    }
  });
  }

}
```

and under commponet i put the:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.getVillages();

....
}
```

and here to load as the chain dropdown

```
  onSubDistrictSelected(subDistrictId: number) {
    if (subDistrictId) {
      this.onLoading.emit(true);
      this.customer.subDistrict = this.subDistricts.filter(c => (c.id == subDistrictId))[0].name;
      this.customer.sdid = subDistrictId;
      this.customer.subDistrictId = subDistrictId;
      this.villages = this.getVillages().filter((item) => {
      return item.subDistrictId === Number(subDistrictId)
      });
      this.onLoading.emit(false);
    }
  }
```

I got error when compile said: **this.getVillages** is not function, But is working correctly if i put the json value inside the component file:

```
getVillages() {
    return [
      { json_data}
      ]
    }
```

What I want to achieved is I want to used the JSon file instead put directly inside the commponet.

Thanks,

Comment: you are saying ngOnInit is not inside your component?

Comment: Hi @yashpatelyk, I put this ngOnInit app.component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getVillages` is a method in service, so you need to instantiate the service before you use it.

First you need to provide the `RecordsService` in a module, like,

**app.module.ts**

```
...
providers : [
    RecordsService
]
...
```

And in your component,

**abc.component.ts**

```
constructor(public recordService : RecordsService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.recordService.getVillages();
}
```

Let me know if you still get the error or have some different error.

***EDIT***:

`getVillages()` is returning an Observable, so you need to subscribe in order to use the data returned.

```
this.recordService.getVillages().subscribe( data => {
    console.log(data);
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, will try it.

Comment: Hi @yashpatelyk, I tried this but it said cannot find name RecordService :(. Same error when I am used the original service name VillageService

Comment: can you share your code on stackBlitz? I will help you debug.